# paste not returning values concatenated

Tags: r

I am trying to get the column names of a dataframe to use them in another call, but this apply call returns the values separated, instead of concatenated correctly. What did I do wrong here?

```
df<-data.frame(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6))
colnames(df)<-c("hi","bye")
apply(df,2,function(x){
    paste("subscale_scores$",colnames(x),sep="")

#this is the command I am eventually trying to run      
 #lm(paste("subscale_scores",colnames(x))~surveys$npitotal+ipip$extraversion+ipip$agreeableness+ipip$conscientiousness+ipip$emotionalStability+ipip$intelImagination)
})
```

Goal output:

```
subscale_scores$hi
subscale_scores$bye
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there any need for the `apply`?

Is this what you mean?

```
paste0('subscale_scores$', names(df))
# [1] "subscale_scores$hi"  "subscale_scores$bye"
```

if you need them concatenated by newline say, add `, sep='\n'`.

The `paste0` is shorthand for `paste(..., sep="")`.

---

A note on your `lm` call later - if you want to do `lm(Y ~ ...)` where `Y` is each of your columns separately, try:

```
lms <- lapply(colnames(df),
              function (y) {
                  # construct your formula
                  frm <- paste0('subscale_scores$', y, ' ~ surveys$npitotal+ipip$extraversion+ipip$agreeableness+ipip$conscientiousness+ipip$emotionalStability+ipip$intelImagination')
                  lm(frm)
              })
names(lms) <- colnames(df)
```

Then `lms$hi` will contain the output of `lm(subscale_scores$hi ~ ...)` and so on.

Or if the aim was to combine all the columns together (`Y1 + Y2 ~ ...`)

Then `paste0('subscale_scores$', names(df), collapse='+')` will give you  `subscale_scores$hi+subscale_scores$bye`

Comment: I think OP might be looking for `paste(..., collapse = "+")`, as it looks like maybe building a formula.

Comment: My goal was to do lm(y~) where y is a column like you thought. I tried your solution and got `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : attempt to apply non-function ` any idea why?

Comment: I would need a reproducible example for that. It happens when (e.g.) you have a dataframe called `df` and then you try to write `df(x)` as if it were a function, or if (say) in your formula you do `a(b + c)` instead of `a * (b + c)` - it thinks you are calling function `a` on `b + c` rather than multiplying.

Comment: Just tried it with a simpler dataset and it worked perfectly.

Comment: my issue was that I had a space in the variable name. To fix this I had to surround the var name with single quotes

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
unlist(lapply(colnames(df),function(x){
    paste("subscale_scores$",x,sep="")
}))
```